# Bash: Appending different strings to specific lines in a file

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, append

let's say I have a file that looks like this:

```
The
Way
Direct
5.0 0.0 3.0
2.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 0.0 2.0
3.0 4.0 6.0
0.000 1.000 2.000
1.0 2.0 3.0
4.0 5.0 6.0
3.0 2.0 0.0
```

I'd like to change this such that it looks like this:

```
The
Way
Direct
5.0 0.0 3.0 U
2.0 0.0 0.0 U
0.0 0.0 1.0 U
0.0 0.0 2.0 U
3.0 4.0 6.0 U
0.000 1.000 2.000 A
1.0 2.0 3.0 A
4.0 5.0 6.0 A
3.0 2.0 0.0 A
```

So after the line "Direct," I have "U" appended to the next x lines, and then at the line "0.000 1.000 2.000" I append "A" to this line and all the ones after it. Another way to look at it is I append "U" to lines 4-8 and append "A" to 9-12.

It seems like awk might be the best way to do this. I know if I use "sed -e 's/$/ U/', it will append U to the end of all the lines... but is there a way to do this for specific lines, as well as append "A"? Thanks!

edit: I also tried picking out specific lines by using sed -n '4, 9p'. However, I am not sure how to append this to adding strings, as: sed -n '4,8p' | sed -e 's/$/ U/' myfile.txt. However, that appends U to all the lines.

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: I tried: sed -e 's/$/ U/' which works generally but not for my specific cases. I also tried: sed -n '4, 12p' -e 's/$/ U/'  to see if that would work, which it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '4,8 s/$/ U/; 9,$ s/$/ A/;'
```

4,8, select lines 4 to 8,

9,$, select lines from 9 to end of file

Comment: Thank you! This works well. Do you know if there is a way to do this by finding the specific line after another line too (in this case, Direct)?